# AWS API timeout - Same code and one is faster than the other

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core

I'm new to the AWS world and I faced this request timeout problem, here is a global view of the architecture:

[image: Architecture1]

I have two relatively similar environments (PROD & TEST) with the ***same code*** (.NET Core) and same architecture as above, but when running the exact ***same test*** on the TEST environment it takes about 13 seconds, however when running it again against the PROD environment, surprisingly, it takes 44 seconds, I get a timeout because as you know the AWS API Gateway is limited to only 29s. Here is what I got in AWS CloudWatch:

> ***TEST Environment:*** Duration: 1268.89 ms Billed Duration: **1269 ms** Memory Size: 3072 MB Max Memory Used: 150 MB

> ***PROD Environment:*** Duration: 43032.07 ms Billed Duration: **43033 ms** Memory Size: 3008 MB Max Memory Used: 204 MB

One other thing to note is that, in the PROD environment, there is only one  Redis node (I don't know if that's related).

My question is, according to your experience, what could be the reasons behind this weird behavior, even though everything looks the same(I could be wrong though)?

**Updates:**

I found the following issue and it is also related to this one:
[Weird Redis behaviour - Value could not be saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71558329/weird-redis-behaviour-value-could-not-be-saved)

Comment: The first time hitting Lambda in a while can be slow. Is it slow if you hit it a second time a few seconds later? Does it hit Dynamo or ElastiCache? Test may be cached and prod is not, or there is just way more data on Dynamo without an index

Comment: @GarrGodfrey I tried the same test several times in both, and both hit Redis first

Comment: @GarrGodfrey thanks a lot, do you know how can I verify that there are a lot of data on DynamoDB without index (Sorry I'm new to AWS), I would really appreciate it, if you have some kind of link to share so I can learn more about that

Comment: idk what your test is, but you need to narrow down which part is slow. run tests that ONLY hit redis and others that only hit dynamodb

Comment: @GarrGodfrey thanks, I'll try to do that, BTW, I did also a test where the business logic behind lambda is local (so I'm able to debug it) which connects to DynamoDB in the cloud and Redis is local and response was fast

Comment: I added one other Redis node but no luck

Comment: Is there a way to debug an AWS Lambda on the cloud maybe?

Comment: I don't see how this question can be answered as it is. You really need to add more logging to your Lambda function to log the timings of calls to Redis and DynamoDB. You also need to make sure you aren't hitting cold start issues in Lambda (that will be in the logs as well). Then update your question with the exact details of those timings.

Comment: Also, you need to show if you are doing a `scan` or a `query` against DynamoDB (or maybe just include your entire function code in the question). And include the number of items in your DynamoDB tables in both environments.

Comment: @MarkB thanks for the comment ... I'm doing a query against DynamoDB ... and the lambda is getting three items from the cache and updating one item when it finishes

Comment: @MarkB the lambda has a lot of dependent projects .... I started to think maybe something related to the config in PROD because the code is the same in the two environments and also the test is the same (I created new items for each environment in order to test)

Comment: That's fine, but as I stated, your question doesn't have enough information to provide an actual answer, and your comments aren't really providing the necessary details. At the very least you need to add some logs to show the timings of your Lambda function's calls to DynamoDB and Redis, and then use that to narrow down where the issue is.

Comment: @MarkB I got you ...  and I'll try to do as you said to narrow down where the issue is.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: If the architecture is same and also the test case then the bottleneck comes down to the calls being made to redis/dynamo. Also you may reduce cold starts with provisioned concurrency but before that, compare the timings of the bottlenecks in both the environments.

Comment: @N.Pamnani you are right and here is what I found:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71558329/weird-redis-behaviour-value-could-not-be-saved